# PHP How to find maximum allowed POST data?

Tags: php, post

In PHP, is there a quick way to find the maximum allowed size of POST data for any server configuration that my script is run on?

For example, `$max_post_length = $_SERVER['maxpost'];` or something.  Perhaps it would return `0` for 'no limit'...any ideas?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use [`ini_get`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-get.php).

```
ini_get('post_max_size');
```

Answer (score 19):

Try this:

```
echo ini_get('post_max_size');
```

Or translate it to bytes:

```
echo (int)(str_replace('M', '', ini_get('post_max_size')) * 1024 * 1024);
```